# Java castor using custom field handlers

Tags: java, xml, field, castor

I have been trying to write a custom field handler which returns the hash code of a java.awt.Image object when writing to XML and retrieves an image based on this hash code when binding the XML to an object.  For some reason, I can't get this to work; castor, from what I can tell, simply instantiates the field handler and then doesn't call any of its methods.

Can you give me a quick example of how to do this because I must be missing something simple!

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Pasting your code can be a good idea. Anyway following works fine for me

```
<m:class name="someClass">
        <m:map-to xml="class"/>
        <m:field name="lineColor" type="java.awt.Color"  handler="ColorFieldHandler">
            <m:bind-xml name="lineColor" node="attribute"/>
        </m:field>
    </m:class>
```

And the handler itself

```
public class ColorFieldHandler extends GeneralizedFieldHandler {
    public Object convertUponGet(Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Integer colorHash = (Integer) value;
    ...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Actualy that's just an example from my project, slightly modified. Of course you should change type attribute to apropriate and implement method convertUponSet

Comment: Huh... forgot to check the date of the question, but anyway... xD